# Pandas Fill na only if there is a value at a later row

Tags: python, pandas

If you have a pandas dataframe

```
A    B    C
1    1    NA
2    1    1
3    NA   3
NA   NA   NA
4    NA   NA
5    NA   4
```

I only want to ffill na's if there is a value between the NA and the end of the dataframe. Is this possible?

So the output will be

```
A    B    C
1    1    NA
2    1    1
3    NA   3
3    NA   3
4    NA   3
5    NA   4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) with `ffill` for forward filling and test nonmissing values with back filling:

```
df = df.mask(df.ffill().notnull(),df.bfill())
```

Or [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with `DataFrame` contructor:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.where(df.ffill().notnull(),df.bfill(), df), 
                  index=df.index, 
                  columns=df.columns)
```

---

```
print (df)
     A    B    C
0  1.0  1.0  NaN
1  2.0  1.0  1.0
2  3.0  NaN  3.0
3  4.0  NaN  4.0
4  4.0  NaN  4.0
5  5.0  NaN  4.0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot - this sorted the problem nicely

Answer (score 3):

Use `ffill` and `bfill`.

```
df.ffill().where(df.bfill().notna())
# Or,
# df.where(df.bfill().isna(), df.ffill())

     A    B    C
0  1.0  1.0  NaN
1  2.0  1.0  1.0
2  3.0  NaN  3.0
3  3.0  NaN  3.0
4  4.0  NaN  3.0
5  5.0  NaN  4.0
```

Comment: @fred.schwartz uh, you can only accept just one answer :(